# how to implement sharding in mongodb and what happens to _id field when collection is on multiple shards?

Tags: mongodb

what is the maximum database size limit for mongo DB on 64bit machine? how to implement SHARDING when database size grows? and how a collection data is stored among multiple shards? what happens to _id field when collection is on multiple shards?

Comment: One question per question, is how this works. Too many things will be considered too broad and closed quickly. Additionally, stackoverflow is for "programming" topics. There are other sites in the stackexchange network for database administration, etc.

Comment: Did you try going through http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/ ?

Comment: Sorry, Neil, you are right, of course. Changing back and forth between Quora and SO makes me forget this, sometimes. ;)

Comment: Most of these are valid individual questions, but you should be able to Google some of these and the others to break out individual questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A single mongod instance can hold up to 64TB of journaled data under Linux and 4TB under Windows. As a sharded cluster may consist of several hundred shards, the size of a sharded database (or more specifically, the sharded collections of a database) is to be considered unlimited for all practical purposes.
2. Sharding is done on a collection level. Actually, it is very easy to add a shard to a sharded cluster. Basically you have to fire up a replica set and add it to the sharded cluster by issuing sh.addHost(replica-set-name/hostname[:port]) and mongoDB takes care of the rest, namely balancing out the amount of data which is stored on each shard. Note that using standalone instances as shards is highly discouraged and may result in loss of data, inconsistent databases and extended down times as well as increased development times (as you need to build an application which can deal with partial results).
3. mongoDB uses range based sharding using the chosen shard key. Each shard stores the range of documents which have a shard key within it's designated range. The `mongos` instance used to access the data will receive those ranges from so called config servers, which are part of the cluster. What happens when a client wants to write or access data is that either the query is sent to a specific shard which is the designated shard if the query contains the shard key or the query is sent to all shards if the query does not contain the shard key. Ok, this is a bit of an oversimplification, but in general, it works that way.
4. The `_id` field may be the shard key (as any other field can) but since it is monotonically increasing (assuming you are using the default ObjectId), it is a poor choice unless hashed: `sh.shardCollection("theCollection":{"_id":"hashed"})`. Other than that it will "only" have the advantage that the individual shards of the cluster will hold an index of the `_id`s they hold and can find those documents without doing a full scan of the collection, which can be *extremely* costly in large collections.

You might want to have a look into [the excellent documentation of mongoDB about sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/) for the details.

Comment: You are invited to vote up the answer and maybe even accept it ;)